# Google Apps Script - web form to update sheet and send email for invoice/expenses

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

Working for a very small business, and boss wants to implement a better system for submitting expenses and invoices for approval. Obviously there are lots of different ways of doing this a SaaS options online - but nearly all of these cost, and are more complicated than we need. A simple google form would be ideal, and we use Google Apps for most of our work stuff - but you cannot attach files to that. So I discovered Google Apps Script, and found some good examples on the google page and on here that helped me on my way.

If I explain what I'm trying to do:

- A member of staff goes to the form, puts in their details, the value
  of the expense, what it's for and attaches a file (pdf or photo
  usually).
- They press submit and this file gets uploaded into a folder in our
  shared google drive.
- It also gets logged into a shared spreadsheet which contains all
  these details and the status of each submission, and a link to the
  file in the drive
- Depending on the cost of the expense, it either gets emailed
  immediately to our accounts person to pay, or it gets sent to the
  boss to approve before paying it.

Now, I have a script that works for the form submission and it correctly uploads the file and logs it in a sheet. But I can't work out how to combine this with the MailApp.sendEmail/GmailApp.sendEmail functions.

Below is the code that does work. The Code.gs file:

```
var submissionSSKey = 'xxxxxxx';
var folderId = "xyxyxyx";


function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html');
  template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return template.evaluate();
}


function processForm(theForm) {
  var fileBlob = theForm.myFile;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var doc = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Thanks.html');
  var name = template.name = theForm.name;
  var reason = template.reason = theForm.reason;
  var email = template.email = theForm.email;
  var cost = template.cost = theForm.cost;
  var payee = template.payee = theForm.payee;
  var fileUrl = template.fileUrl = doc.getUrl();
  var threshold = 100;

  if (cost > threshold)
  {
    var approval = "YES"
    }
  else
  {
    var approval = "NO"
  }
  var timestamp = new Date() 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 8).setValues([[timestamp,name,cost,payee,reason,approval,"Submitted",fileUrl]]);

   // Return HTML text for display in page.
  return template.evaluate().getContent();

}
```

And the Form.Html file:

```
<script>
  // Javascript function called by "submit" button handler,
  // to show results.
  function updateOutput(resultHtml) {
    toggle_visibility('inProgress');
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = resultHtml;
  }

  // From blog.movalog.com/a/javascript-toggle-visibility/
  function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
    else
      e.style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>

<div id="formDiv">
<!-- Form div will be hidden after form submission -->
<form id="myForm">

    Name: <input name="name" type="text" /><br/>
    Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br/>
    Payee: <input name="payee" type="text" /><br/>
    Cost of invoice/expense: <input name="cost" type="number" /><br/>
    Reason: <textarea name="reason" style="margin: 2px; height: 148px; width: 354px;"></textarea><br/>
    Upload file/image: <input name="myFile" type="file" /><br/>
  <input type="button" value="Submit"
      onclick="toggle_visibility('formDiv'); toggle_visibility('inProgress');
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
          .processForm(this.parentNode)" />
</form>
</div>

<div id="inProgress" style="display: none;">
<!-- Progress starts hidden, but will be shown after form submission. -->
Uploading. Please wait...
</div>

<div id="output">
  <!-- Blank div will be filled with "Thanks.html" after form submission. -->
</div>
```

And this is the email function I want to create and send as the next step, but I have tried a few different things and cannot work out how to fit this in with what I have above.

```
function sendEmails() {
    //New vars

  var bossEmail = "email address1";
  var accountsEmail = "email address2";
  var messageBoss = "<html><body>"
    + "<p>" + "Hi Boss,"
    + "<p>" + name + " has submitted an invoice/expense that needs your approval since it is above £." + threshold
    + "<p>" + "This is to pay £" + cost + "to" + reason
    + "<p>" + reason
    + "<p>" + "The invoice can be found attached to this email or here in our google drive:" + fileUrl
    + "<p>" + "Please approve or reject the expense report here:" + approvalUrl
    + "</body></html>";

  var messageAccounts = "<html><body>"
    + "<p>" + "Hi XX,"
    + "<p>" + name + " has submitted an invoice/expense that needs to be paid."
    + "<p>Amount" + "This is to pay £" + cost + "to" + payee
    + "<p>Reason:" + reason
    + "<p>" + "The invoice can be found attached to this email or here in our google drive:" + fileUrl
    + '<p>Please approve or reject the expense report <a href="' + approvalUrl + '">here</a>.'
    + "</body></html>";
  if (cost > threshold)
  {
     var recipient = bossEmail
     var subject = name + "has submitted an invoice that needs your approval"
     var emailText = messageBoss
    }
  else
  {
    var recipient = accountsEmail
    var subject = name + "has submitted an invoice to be paid"
    var emailText = messageAccounts;
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient,subject,emailText);  
}
```

Any help or advice would be much appreciated - am new to this and learning as I go!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add some parameters to the sendEmails() function, such as :

```
sendEmails(accountsEmail,name,cost,threshold,payee,reason,fileUrl)
```

Then, you call it just before the end of your processForm() function with the right variables :

```
sendEmails(email,name,cost,threshold,payee,reason,fileUrl);
```

Also please note that your "approval" var in your processForm() function is not visible when you call the setValues() ... I suggest to declare it just before the "if" statement :

```
  var approval;
  if (cost > threshold)
  {
    approval = "YES"
  }
  else
  {
    approval = "NO"
  }
```